# Automator Shortcut only working in Textedit but not other

Tags: javascript, variables, typeerror, automator

I've been trying to run a piece of code in Automator. It is supposed to reformat text for me when it is correctly run. It gets the input from the clipboard and then outputs in the form of clipboard as well. I could get it to work in textedit and chrome when I apply the keyboard shortcut to which I assigned it. However, it does not work when I try to apply it in an application called Anki. I am guessing it might have to do with the fact it's text input, but that does not make too much sense.

Is there a solution?

Code (which is working, and for your reference):

```
function run(input, parameters) {

var someText = input[0]
someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm," ");

someText = someText.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
someText = someText.replace(/(\s)([a-z])[.]/g, '\n$1 $2.');
someText = someText.replace(/(\s)([A-Z])([.])/g, '\n$1 $2.');
someText = someText.replace(/(\s)(\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)([.|:|)])(\s)/g, '\n\n$2'+'. ');

//Other features: lines for bracketed letters and numbers
someText = someText.replace(/([(])(\d|\d\d|\d\d\d)([)])/g, '\n$2'+'.');
someText = someText.replace(/([(])([A-Z]|[a-z])([)])/g, '\n $2'+'.');

//Replace the wor- d dash thingy in case onto another line 
someText = someText.replace(/([a-z])([-])(\s)([a-z])/g, '$1$4');

let words = someText.split(' ');

input[0] = (words.join(' '));

// consider the modifications for F. etc or 1. 2. 3. as well as a) b) c). Maybe not a. b. because words do end with that
//  return (input[0].unwrap);


return input[0];
}
```

[Screenshot of how the workflow is like, note 'any application' is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircYq.jpg)

Comment: Show your current code, please.

Comment: @red_menace There you go. Thanks for your attention!